# Example using autoInitializePage in JQueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am looking for a simple example showing how to use JQueryMobile to render a page that has been dynamically assembled on the client side. $.mobile.autoInitialize used to work a few versions ago, and now we have $.mobile.autoInitializePage but I can't seem to figure out how to do it or find any examples of people that are using it.

My best effort (**THIS NOW WORKS** - was calling setting autoInitializePage too early before):

```html
<html> 
  <head> 
    <link class="jsbin" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script class="jsbin" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.js"></script> 
    <script> 
      $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false
    </script> 
  </head> 
  <body>
</body> 
  <!-- coffeescript makes multiline strings easy --> 
  <script src="http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/extras/coffee-script.js"></script> 
  <script type='text/coffeescript'> 
    $('body').html "
      <div data-role='page'>
        <div data-role='header'><h1>Title</h1></div>
        <div data-role='content'><p>Page content goes here.</p></div>
        <div data-role='footer'><h4>Page Footer</h4></div>
      </div>
    ";
    $.mobile.initializePage();
  </script> 
</html>
```

Result here: http://jsbin.com/apocol/2
Mess around with it here: http://jsbin.com/apocol/2/edit#html

Comment: My problem was that I was setting $.mobile.autoInitializePage = false before loading jquery mobile. I have now fixed it above and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of the performance impact or other possible gotchas but I have used this successfully with dynamically updated pages when I want to force a complete refresh.

```
$("#MyPage").page("destroy").page();
```