# Is there a way to detect the first page loading in Jquery Mobile from another plugin?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile, event-listener

I'm looking for a way to tap into JQM and override stuff BEFORE the first page is being loaded.

JQM initializes like so (from latest JQM code):

```
( function( $, window, undefined ) {
    var $html = $( "html" ),
    $head = $( "head" ),
    $window = $( window );

    // trigger mobileinit event 
    $( window.document ).trigger( "mobileinit" );

    ... 

    $.extend($.mobile, {
        // find and enhance the pages in the dom and transition to the first page.
        initializePage: function() {

            ...
            // alert listeners that the pagecontainer has been determined for binding
            // to events triggered on it
            $window.trigger( "pagecontainercreate" );
            ...
```

So there are **two events** I could tap into: **mobileinit** and **pagecontainercreate**. I know this is easy from the HTML like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( window ).bind( 'pagecontainercreate', function() {
        console.log("HELLO");
        });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.1.0.multiview_con.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin.js"></script>
```

But what if I wanted to bind to these events from INSIDE plugin.js sitting AFTER JQM? If I put the same listener inside plugin.js it never fires. I assume, because it's too late. But I need to preventDefault loading the first page, so as soon as JQM trys to load the inital page, it will be too late for me.

**Question**:
Is there any way to listen to either one of these events or any other event firing before the first page loading commences from a plugin sitting after JQM?

**EDIT**:
I can't use **pageinit**, because it will fire after the call to the first page. Dito for **pageCreate**, which also doesn't fire from inside a plugin.

Comment: Have you tried using `$(document).bind('mobileinit', function(){});` with `$.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;` ?

Comment: can I run this from inside a plugin. I think I would have to set this option in the markup, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291110/example-using-autoinitializepage-in-jquerymobile)?

Comment: You will need to include the `plugin.js` file before the jQuery Mobile include. Or include at least some code before the jQuery Mobile file that binds to the event.

Comment: @Jasper: can't because it's using $.mobile."functions" a lot.

Comment: maybe you would be able to wrap the whole plugin into mobileinit?

Comment: It might help if you shared what you were trying to achieve here.  There may be another approach that would work.

Comment: Ah. Some time ago and I developed a workaround for this (posting in a minute). My original problem was that there is no way to detect, when Jquery Mobile loads the first page from another plugin that is triggered after Jquery Mobile has initiliazed/started loading the first page, because the event listeners I placed in the 2nd plugin where listening for JQM events that had passed already on initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I solved it with JQMs `autoinitialize` option ([see here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html)) to false like so:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
$.mobile.autoInitializePage = false;
});
```

This way Jquery Mobile will not start automatically but only when I call it manually like so:

```
 if ( $.mobile.autoInitializePage == false){
    $.mobile.initializePage();
    }
```

I have placed the last snippet in my 2nd plugin, which needs to setup completely before JQM trigger the first page init. When the 2nd plugin is set, I call `initializePage()` and everything runs ok.